# Do Google Apps accounts ever become inactive?

Tags: google-workspace, account-management

I know that Gmail accounts will become inactive after several months of inactivity. I'm wondering if the same thing will happen with a Google Apps account.

Specifically, I want to set up Google Apps Email on a domain which I will never log in to and have all the messages forwarded to another account.

I know I can set up POP3 access to keep it alive, but I'm wondering if this way is possible too.

**Update:** [According to Google](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=38173), the email account won't become disabled. However, I'm wondering if the domain might get disabled since I don't log in to it anymore. Obviously if the domain would get disabled, it's safe to assume that the email would no longer work as well.

So I'm wondering if Google Apps will ever get disabled due to inactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking if the account will be deleted?  If so, the answer is no according to [Google](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=38173).

> Google will not delete inactive email
>   accounts on your domain. Instead, as
>   an administrator, you can create and
>   delete email accounts on your domain
>   when necessary.

EDIT:  Once the account is setup, it doesn't seem like it but I'm not certain.  There's no mention of inactivity other than verifying the setup here:  http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33419

> Your account has been deactivated or deleted.
>   For example, Google deactivates your account if you do not complete the steps required to verify ownership of the domain within 14 days (7 days for Standard Edition). It is also possible for an administrator at your domain to manually delete the account. In either case, you will need to go to http://www.google.com/a to reregister your domain. You will have to wait five days from the time the account was deleted before reregistering. Any data in the deleted account will be lost.

Comment: I just found that link too. I updated the question to explain it better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Free Google Apps accounts that have not been used for a year will be deactivated. The administrator will first receive some warning emails like this:

*"We noticed that you haven’t used your Google Apps account for the domain domain.net in over a year. Please let us know if you’d like to keep this account.*

*If we don’t hear from you in 30 days, your domain.net Google Apps account will be automatically closed."*

Comment: Do you have any official reference for this?

Comment: @AndrewLott bunch of my acquaintances have received the same email